# Position attribute for record component offset

Tags: ada

How to get offset in bytes for a record component?

From [Ada Programming/Attributes/'Position](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Attributes/'Position)

> 'Position is a record type component attribute. It represents the address offset of the component from the beginning of the record. The value returned is represented in storage units, which is machine-specific.

Compiling this code:

```
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
procedure Main is
   type R is record
      I : Integer;
      F : Float;
   end record;
begin
   Put(R.I'Position); --9
   Put(R.F'Position); --10
end;
```

results in:

```
main.adb:9:08: invalid prefix in selected component "R"
main.adb:10:08: invalid prefix in selected component "R"
```

I don't know why I cant compile that?

- The offset for *R.I* should be *0*.
- The offset for *R.F* should be *Integer'Size/Storage_Unit*.

For example, equivalently look at C++ [offsetof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/) documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the Reference Manual ([RM 13.5.2](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-13-5-2.html)), you'll see that `R.C'Position` is defined

> For a component C of a composite, non-array object R

which means it won't work for a type as in your code. You need to create a variable:

```
   Foo : R;
begin
   Put(Foo.I'Position); --9
   Put(Foo.F'Position); --10
```

So the example in the wikibook seems to be wrong.

Comment: Does creating a variable for the purpose to retrieve offset: allocates memory?

Comment: In this case, it will reserve space on the stack.

Comment: You could use a declare block; the storage should be freed on exiting the block.

Comment: @Jossi It's a good question to ask why they didn't allow `R.I'Position`, which perhaps would have made more sense.  The only reason I can think of is that there is no other context in which <type>.<component> is allowed, outside of the definition of the type (or the body of the type, if it's a task or protected type).  So perhaps the language designers decided it wasn't worthwhile to add a special-case syntax for a couple attributes, especially since it would be uncommon to want to use those attributes if you don't have an actual object to work with.

Comment: @SimonWright Actually, if the object in your `declare` block is used only to get the `'Position`, a good compiler would realize the object is never actually used, and refuse to allocate any storage in the first place.